# javascript ajax callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding the `ajax` `callback` function

I have

```
test = function(){
  this.items=[];
}

//original state.
test.prototype.getListItems = function (){

    this.items.push('test item');
    this.handleItems();

}

//this method will be called if the user clicks a button.
test.prototype.clickBtn = function (){

    this.ajGetOneMoreItem()    
    this.handleItems();
}

//a callback function that will add a new item.
test.prototype.ajGetOneMoreItem = function (){
   var that=this;    
     ajax.callback = function(dataItem){
         that.items.push(dataItem);
     }    
}

//to show the items.
test.prototype.handleItems = function (){

       //only show the test item, but not dataItem after user clicks a button.
      console(this.items)

}


var testObj = new test();

$('#testBtn).click(function(){
   testObj.clickBtn();
})
```

I want to show the new items that was added through the user.
However, it only appears this.items only show the first '`test item`' but did not add the new `dataItem`. Am I missing something here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your AJAX call is likely asynchronous. This means `this.handleItems()` will run before the AJAX responds with the new data. Do some logging in various places like your callback, and you'll see that the code runs out of order.

Comment: This must be the question of the century with hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invocation of:

```
this.ajGetOneMoreItem();
```

completes almost instantly. This means the next step:

```
this.handleItems();
```

happens before the AJAX callback has been executed. To solve this problem, move the second step into the callback.

```
test.prototype.ajGetOneMoreItem = function (){
   var that=this;    
     ajax.callback = function(dataItem){
         that.items.push(dataItem);
         that.handleItems();
     }    
}
```

Comment: `this.handleItems();` will likely fail because `this` is most likely redefined. And `$('#testBtn').click(testObj.clickBtn);` is wrong because the method loses its reference to `testObj`. OP is doing it correctly.